# How to change Clion build directory

Tags: makefile, cmake, clion, ctest

I am learning to use CLion IDE these days. I am trying to change the default path of build directory:

```
~/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/AFQMCLIB-83788a76/83788a76/Debug
```

I can change by:

1. Go to `build execution deployment`
2. Click `cmake`
3. Change `build output path` to `MYPATH`

After making this change. I rebuild my code, all the targets now appears in `MYPATH/Debug/`, however there is no Makefile in `MYPATH/Debug/`.

I am using CTest, I want to run `make test` to test my program. If there is no Makefile in `MYPATH`, I need to run every test executable to test my code. (I will have a lot of executable, it is not convenient to run them individually )

Is there a way to move everything in build to `MYPATH`? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to wait:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CLION/Roadmap+for+CLion+2016.3

> #### Cmake:
>
> Ability to specify the build/generation output directory.